# Pointer syntax and incrementation

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 

void reverse(char* str){
    char *end = str; 
    char tmp; 
    if(str){
        cout << "hello" << endl;
        while(*end){
            cout << end << endl;
            ++end; 
        }

        --end; 

        while (str < end){
            tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end; 
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "helloyouarefunny"; 
    string input = str; 
    reverse(str); 
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        cout << str[i]; 
    }
}
```

1. Is `if(str){}` equivalent to `if(str == NULL){}`?
2. What does `while(*end){}` mean and what is it exactly doing? I think I have a general understanding that the while loop will continue to be executed as long as it does not "see" a `'\0'`. But I am not sure what is *exactly* going on with this line of code.
3. Given that `if(str){}` is an equivalent statement to `if(str == NULL){}`, what would you pass into a function to make `str = NULL`? For example, in my `main(){}`, I tried to do `char str[] = NULL`, thereby, attempting to pass a NULL so that it wouldn't go inside the code `if(str == NULL){}`. But I get an error saying I cannot make this declaration `char str[] = NULL`. So my question is why am I getting this error and what can I pass through the `reverse()` function in order to make the code inside of `if(str){}` not execute? I hope this question made sense.
4. And the code `++end` is doing pointer arithmetic correct? So every time it is incremented, the address is moving to the address right next to it?
5. I'm a little confused `while(str < end){}`. What is the difference between just `str` and `*str`? I understand that `cout << str << endl;` has to do with overloading the operator `<<` and therefore prints the entire string that is passed through the argument. But why, when I `cout << *end << endl;`, it only prints the character at that memory address? So my question is, what's the difference between the two? Is it just dereferencing when i do `*str`? I might actually be asking more than that question in this question. I hope I don't confuse you guys >_<.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you. One question though, for the line, (str++) = *end;, str is set to *end and then, it is incremented is it not? For example, if we are considering the array of characters, "hello". tmp = h. and then, the index where "e" in "hello" should be is replaced with "o" and then *(end--) = h. So now we have, "holho". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So now there are five questions in the question and a sixth in the comments. This isn't a chat room! Please keep it in mind this time and fix the post.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `if(str){}` equivalent to `if(str == NULL){}`?

No, `if(str){}` is equivalent to `if(str != NULL){}`

> What does `while(*end){}` mean and what is it exactly doing?

Since the type of of `end` is `char*`, `while(*end){}` is equivalent to `while (*end != '\0')`. The loop is executed for all the characters of the input string. When the end of the string is reached, the loop stops.

> Given that `if(str){}` is an equivalent statement to `if(str == NULL){}`

That is not correct. I did not read rest of the paragraph since you start out with an incorrect statement.

> And the code `++end` is doing pointer arithmetic correct? So every time it is incremented, the address is moving to the address right next to it?

Sort of. The value of `end` is incremented. It points to the next object that it used to point to before the operation.

> I'm a little confused `while(str < end){}`

In the previous `while` loop, `end` was incremented starting from `str` until it reached the end of the string. In this loop, `end` is decremented until it reaches the start of the string. When `end` reaches `str`, the conditional of the `while` statement evaluates to `false` and the loop breaks.

**Update**

Regarding

> what would you pass into a function to make `str = NULL`?

You could simply call

```
reverse(NULL);
```

> I tried to do `char str[] = NULL;`

`str` is an array of characters. It can be initialized using couple of ways:

```
 // This is what you have done.
 char str[] = "helloyouarefunny"; 

 // Another, more tedious way:
 char str[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','y','o','u','a','r','e','f','u','n','n','y', '\0'};
```

Notice the presence of an explicitly specified null character in the second method.

You cannot initialize a variable that is of type array of `char`s to to NULL. The language does not allow that. You can initialize a pointer to NULL but not an array.

```
char* s1 = NULL;   // OK
reverse(s1);       // Call the function

s1 = malloc(10);   // Allocate memory for the pointer.
strcpy(s1, "test") // Put some content in the allocated memory
reverse(s1);       // Call the function, this time with some content.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please answer question 3? Given that if(str){} is an equivalent statement to if(str != NULL){}?

Comment: Thank you. That's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

These are pretty standard C programming idioms.

1. No, in fact `if (str) ...` is equivalent to `if (str != NULL) ...`
2. C character strings are null terminated, meaning that "Hello" is represented in memory as the character array `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`. As with pointers, the 0 or NULL value is considered `false` in a logical expression. Thus `while (*end) ...` will execute the body of the `while` loop so long as `end` has not reached the null character.
3. N/A
4. Correct - this advances to the next character in the string, or to the null terminator.
5. This is the reverse algorithm. After the first loop, `end` points to one past the end of the string and `str` points to the beginning. Now we work these two pointers toward each other, swapping characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response what is the difference between cout << str << endl; and cout << *str << endl;?

Comment: `cout << str << endl` will output a character string and `cout << *str << endl` will output the character pointed at by str.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1/2) In C and C++, whatever is in the `if` or `while` is evaluated as a boolean.  `0` is evaluated to false while *any other value* is evaluated to true. Given that `NULL` is equivalent to `0`, `if(str)` and `if(str != NULL)` do the same things.

Likewise, `while(*end)` will only loop so long as the value `end` is pointing to does not evaluate to `0`.

3) If you pass a `char` pointer to this function, it could be the null pointer (`char *str = 0`), so you're checking to make sure `str` is not `null`.

4) Yes, the pointer is then pointing to the next location in memory until eventually you find the `null` at the end of the string.

5) Perhaps your confusion is based around the fact that the code is missing parenthesis, the loop should look like:

```
while (str < end){
    tmp = *str;
    *(str++) = *end; 
    *(end--) = tmp;
}
```

So that the two pointers will continue to make there way towards eachother until crossing paths (at which point, `str` will no longer be less than `end`)

Comment: _"yes, `if(str)` and `if(str == NULL)` do the same things."_ I'll have whatever you're having mate!

Comment: Thank you for your response. One question, for the line, *(str++) = *end;, str* is set to *end and then, it is incremented is it not? For example, if we are considering the array of characters, "hello". tmp = h. and then, the index where "e" in "hello" should be is replaced with "o" and then *(end--) = h. So now we have, "holho". I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and this is what happens when you try to type quickly. Surprised no one else called me out on that.

Comment: @Jae No, we're setting `*str` to `*end`, not `str`. In your example, `str` would be pointing to the 'h', so the resulting string after that line would be "oello"